# How to find out all the components loading on a page in magnolia?

Tags: java, magnolia

I have a magnolia application. In that I have a component and due to some mistake that component is loading on multiple pages. So I want to find out that for each page what all components are used while making that page using any java code or JavaScript code anything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This small groovy script should give you what you want. You need to run it from within groovy console or as a groovy script from Magnolia groovy module https://gist.github.com/rah003/2cb0110d94a99d4e4832

HTH,
Jan